# Google Sheets: Count of unique items, considering two criterias

Tags: count, unique

I'm looking for a simple way to count unique items based on two criterias. I tried it by myself with various combinations of Arrayformula, Countif, Query, Countuniqueifs and/or Filter, but couldn't make it work.

The [example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPs4niIdZvn5X2GZ22EStJGFIdm1DgZMjzpoZS-Hgjc/edit#gid=0)

I have a list of different IDs (with some gaps in between) in column A and an criteria in column B. The logic I want to have applied is: Sum of all unique IDs, except of 'empty', which have bought=yes.

In the example the following IDs would be legit and have bought=yes:
Apple (row 2)
Juice (row 5)
Kiwi (row 9)
Pear (row 12)

So the result should be: 4

Does anyone have a convenient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are many ways to solve this, I used the QUERY() and UNIQUE() functions

```
=query(UNIQUE(A1:B13); "SELECT COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 = 'yes' LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''"; 1)
```

[image]

Comment: My pleasure and I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: You are welcome, please mark this answer as resolved your question